# Element 'below' a Bootstrap modal not appearing after removing display:none by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

A page includes a 'wait pictogram' that appears whenever a user action triggers an AJAX request. To do that, script `FoxInCloud.js > FoxInCloud.WaitPic()` sets it to `z-order:10000;` and removes `display:none;`

- Pictogram appears fine when user action occurs on the main page;
- It fails to appear when user action takes place on a Bootstrap modal opened 'over' the main page.
- It does appear over the modal when removing the `display:none;` attribute manually using the browser developer tool.

What happens here?

Thanks,

[Test page](http://foxincloud.com/tutotest/bs/)
[Video showing the behavior](https://youtu.be/izyb0JIB778)
Bootstrap 3.3.7